# VS code "run without debugging" is not working for JavaScript code

Tags: node.js, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Hi I have a problem with the VSC when I try to run a js code without debugging there is no result in the console and the bar for debugging is shown and I can not stop it after a while just disapears on his own.
I am working on win11 and this is happening since yesterday before all was working fine.
I did not made any update also.
I would appreciate any help as I am new in programming please feel free to ask me for more details for resolving this issue. Thanks in advance for your effort :)

[This is the .json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZzTD.png)

[The js file is running using CTRL+F5 without debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwRQ1.png)

When I go to .json the workspace is not changed as my folder where I have the code.

This is what I have on the debug console:

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\

Process exited with code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.